# Eliminating $t$ from the system $x=x_0+a\cos(wt-kx_0)$, $y=y_0+a\cos(wt-ky_0)$, and identifying the locus of $(x,y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Given
> $$x= x_0 + a \cos (wt-kx_0)$$
> $$y= y_0 + a \cos (wt-ky_0)$$
> where $x$, $x_0$ , $y$ , $y_0$ , $a$ , $w $ and $k $ are real numbers, write a combined equation to eliminate $t$ from
> this system.

I have tried this a lot but couldn't go further ahead. I tried using inverse functions but since they don't take the periodicity into account, I rejected the idea. I tried adding, subtracting them but that didn't work either.

> What exactly is the locus of $(x,y)$ in the Cartesian plane?

The answer is that it's a rotated ellipse.

I think it must be centered at ($x_0$,$y_0$), but I can't find a suitable way to solve this.

Can someone provide some approaches/ideas on how to eliminate $t $ from these?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Expand both cosines using $\cos{(a-b)}=\cos{a}\cos{b}+\sin{a}\sin{b}$. Now you have two equations in the two unknowns $\cos{\omega t}$ and $\sin{\omega t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging yields a system of linear equations $(E)$ of two variables $\cos wt$ and $\sin wt $
$$
(E):\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\cos \omega t \cos k x_0+\sin \omega t \sin k x_0=\frac{x-x_0}{a} \\
\cos \omega t \cos k y_0+\sin \omega t \sin k y_0=\frac{y-y_0}{a}
\end{array}\right.\\
$$
Using Crammer’s Rule, we obtain
$$
\cos wt=\frac{\left|\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{x-x_0}{a} & \sin kx_0 \\
\frac{y-y_0}{a} & \sin k y_0
\end{array}\right|}{\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos k x_0 & \sin k x_0 \\
\cos k y_0 & \sin k_0
\end{array}\right|} \textrm{ and } \sin wt=\frac{\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\cos k x_0 & \frac{x-x_0}{a} \\
\cos k y_0 & \frac{y-y_0}{a}
\end{array}\right|}{\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\cos k x_0 & \sin kx_0 \\
\cos k y_0 & \sin k y_0
\end{array}\right|}
$$
Using the identity $ \cos ^2 \omega t+\sin ^2 \omega t=1$, we get the equation of the locus of $(x,y)$ as:
$$
\left|\begin{array}{cc}
x-x_0 & \sin k x_0 \\
y-y_0 & \sin k y_0
\end{array}\right|^2+\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\cos k x_0 & x-x_0 \\
\cos ky_0 & y-y_0
\end{array}\right|^2=a^2 \sin k\left(x_0-y_0\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Expand both cosines using $\cos{(a-b)}=\cos{a}\cos{b}+\sin{a}\sin{b}$ then solve the resulting equations in $\cos{\omega t}$ and $\sin{\omega t}$ to get

$$\sin{\omega t}=\frac{\frac{x-x_{0}}{a}\cos{(ky_{0})}-
\frac{y-y_{0}}{a}\cos{(kx_{0})}}{\sin{(kx_{0}-k y_{0})}}\qquad (1)$$

$$\cos{\omega t}=\frac{\frac{x-x_{0}}{a}\sin{(ky_{0})}-
\frac{y-y_{0}}{a}\sin{(kx_{0})}}{\sin{(ky_{0}-k x_{0})}}\qquad (2)$$

Now square both sides of (1) and (2) then add the resulting equations and finally eliminate $t$ using

$$\sin^2{\omega t}+\cos^2{\omega t}=1.$$